# how do I do a collectionGroup query but get the documents that subcollection is inside of?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

how do I do a collectionGroup query but get the documents that subcollection is inside of. My data is structured as:  `Users (collection) -> UID(doc) -> privateData (collection) -> UID (doc)`
and I want to query based on a field in the `UID doc`in the `privateData collection`, but I want the actual data from the `UID Doc` in the `Users collection`

Answer (score 1):

You can't query across multiple collections like this.  If you want data from a different subcollection, then your collection group query will need to target that other subcollection instead.  This means you would probably have to duplicate the fields from privateData collection into the Users collection.  Duplication of field data is common in nosql databases like Firestore.

If you can't duplicate that data for whatever reason (such as privacy), then you would need to query each related document separately, effectively joining each users doc to the matching doc in privateData.

Comment: So, basically there is no good way to, for example, get all the first and last names of people who are in a 10 mile radius from me, if location data is stored in a subcollection?

Comment: What I would have to do is the collection group query which would give me all the UIDs of the people I want to get, then call a getDocument for each of those UIDs?

Comment: With your current data model, there is no way to get it with one query.  As I said in my answer, you will need to either duplicate data or fetch the related documents separately.

Comment: How would you suggest I change my data model? I have location data in the private subcollection, so duplicating data would be out of the question for me

Comment: Copy the fields from the data you need for the query into documents in the users collection.

Comment: It contains location data. If I query for those documents, all the location data will be on the client and that wouldn't be safe. Is there any other solution? I can't imagine that my problem is very unique.

Comment: Please read my answer again.  You have two choices, and no more.

Comment: If you read my previous comment, you would know that I CANNOT duplicate data. Thank you.

Comment: And if you read my answer, you would have the alternative.  It starts with "If you can't duplicate that data for whatever reason".

Comment: I realize. Your alternative, unfortunately, is what I am trying to avoid. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Its not possible.  You have to choose one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your data model, you would have to have a reference to the parent document for the sub collection in the child object, or fetch the document and using the documents snapshot, you can call its parent reference
something like this: `querySnapshot.docs()[x].snapshot.getRef().getParent()`